# How to import data from Excel Online in SSAS Tabular?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sharepoint, ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to connect an Excel Online file in the SSAS tabular model, for this, i'm using the Data Feed connection type but when i insert the spreadsheet link in the data feed URL, the following error appears: *The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.* I don't know what i do, i'm using SSAS on premises.

Resuming: My tabular ssas project is on the internal corporate server and i need to access a sheet that is in the cloud using the SSAS tabular model

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? There is too little info that helpers can use for troubleshooting (IMHO).

Comment: changed !! i don't know if it was clear but that's it, can ask specific questions if you want :)

Comment: Do you provide the correct username and password in your source? Does this user, have access to your excel online?

Comment: So, for me to access the sheet, I need to pass my credentials and the connection method is OAuth, but I can't find a token or something. yes they're correct